# How to set this "slider" to change every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I developed this "slider" in jQuery

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pos-rel text-center">
   <div class="slider-meio slider1">    
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.novahidraulica.com.br/imgcategoria/1/2014-09-24-11-09-0420.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 pos-rel text-center">
   <div class="slider-meio active slider2"> 
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.novahidraulica.com.br/imgcategoria/1/2014-09-24-11-09-0420.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <ul class="controle-slider">
      <li class="active-slider"><a data-target=".slider1" >LINHA FACE PLANA</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-target=".slider2" >LINHA COLHEDORA</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 function montaSlider() {
            $(".slider-meio").each(function () {
                if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                   $(this).fadeIn();
                }else {
                    $(this).fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
        montaSlider();
        $(".controle-slider li a").click(function () {
            $(".controle-slider li a").parent().removeClass("active-slider");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active-slider")
            $(".slider-meio").removeClass("active");
            $($(this).attr("data-target")).addClass("active")
            montaSlider();
        });
```

i want to change the slide every 5 seconds, but i cant think of how to do it

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval) javascript method to call your `montarSlider()` every 5 seconds. Example:

```
var timer = window.seInterval(montarSlider, 5000);
```

I recommend you to store the variable returned by the `setInterval()` method so you can later stop it if necessary.

**EDIT:** Since you also need to rotate the elements with the `active` class, you can first make a function called `slide()` to activate the next element before calling the `montarSlider()` function. Then, instead of set the interval to the `montarSlider()` function, you set it to the `slide()` function. Example:

```
function slide() {
    var currentActive = $(".slider-meio.active");
    var nextActive;
    currentActive.removeClass("active");

    if(currentActive.parent().next().children(".slider-meio").length > 0) {
        nextActive = currentActive.parent().next().children(".slider-meio");
    } else {
        nextActive = $(currentActive.parent().siblings()[0]).children(".slider-meio");
    }
    nextActive.addClass("active");
    montaSlider();
}
var timer = window.seInterval(slide, 5000);
```

Comment: the montarSlider() function changes the slider by fading out all the element then fading in the  elements with the 'ative' ckass, it doesnt change the active class

Comment: CHeck my new edit. Now it moves the active class to the next (or first) element present with 'slider-meio' class.

Comment: thanks man, that worked!! now just for fun, how can i change also the active-slider class on the a tag when it changes

Comment: For that, you can do the same I do to assign the `nextActive` variable in the `slide()` function, but instead of looking for the `.slider-meio` class, you look for the `".controle-slider>li"` matching.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setInterval()` function:

```
var intrvl = setInterval(function(){montaSlider()},5000);
```

I you need to stop it use:

```
clearInterval(intrvl);
```